# Extract some string from the URL

Tags: php, string

I have a URL, e.g:
`https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/`.

From the above URL, I want to extract `my-product-name-display` if this URL contains it, if not, I want the string after `/ex/{BYADE3323}` as below URL does not contain `my-product-name-display`.

`https://www.example.com/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/`

I have tried below code:

```
`$url_param = "https://www.example.com/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/";`
or 
`$url_param = "https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/";`

    $e_product_title = explode('.com/', $url_param);
    if(isset($e_product_title)){
    $product_title = $e_product_title[1];
    //now explode the ex
    $get_asin = explode('/ex/',$product_title);
    $final_product_title = str_replace('-',' ',$get_asin[0]);
    $get_asin_final = explode('/', $get_asin[1]);
    $asin_v2 = $get_asin_final[0];
    }
    else{
        $get_asin = explode('/ex/',$url_param);
        print_r($get_asin);
    }
echo $final_product_title." ".$asin_v2;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want only product title from url like "BYADE3323" right? weather "my-product-name-display" string exist or not?

Comment: I want "my-product-name-display" if exists in url else want "BYADE3323" from url.

Comment: Is BYADE3323 a fixed string or it can have any value a that position?

Comment: "my-product-name-display" can be after .com/ or may not be avilable into URL. if my-product-name-display is not in url then after .com/ex/BYADE3323/ would be found into url, here BYADE3323 and my-product-name-display can not be same, it would be different for every new URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string,

Check if `my-product-name-display` and `BYADE3323` is in the array.

If present, find out `BYADE3323`'s index.

Add 1 to it and check if the next element is present.

```
<?php
$str = 'https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/';
$str = str_replace('://', '__', $str);
$arr = explode('/', $str);
$return = '';
if (in_array('my-product-name-display', $arr) && in_array('BYADE3323', $arr)) {
 $idx = array_search('BYADE3323', $arr);
 $idx2 = $idx + 1;
 if (! empty($idx) && ! empty($arr[$idx2])) {
  $idx += 1;
  $return = $arr[$idx2];
 }
}
echo $return;
```

**EDIT:**

As per comments from OP, following is the program for array of urls and array of search strings.

```
<?php
$searchStrings = [];
$searchStrings[] = ['my-product-name-display', 'BYADE3323'];
$searchStrings[] = ['your-product-name-display', 'BYADE4434'];

$urls = [];
$urls[] = 'https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/';
$urls[] = 'https://www.example.com/your-product-name-display/ex/BYADE4434/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/';
$urls[] = 'https://www.example.com/their-product-name-display/ex/TEST343/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/';
$urls[] = 'https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/ANASDF33/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/';
$urls[] = 'https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/';

$return = [];
if (! empty($urls)) {
 foreach ($urls as $url) {
  if (! empty($searchStrings)) {
   foreach ($searchStrings as $searchString) {
    $str = implode('/ex/', $searchString);
    if (strpos($url, $str) !== false) {
     $arr = explode('/', $url);
     $idx = array_search('BYADE3323', $arr);
     $idx2 = $idx + 1;
     if (! empty($idx) && ! empty($arr[$idx2])) {
      $idx += 1;
      $return[] = $arr[$idx2];
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($return);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf
    [1] => wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf
)
```

Comment: but the my-product-name-display and "BYADE3323" is not static, it can be anything. i have approx 5 Lacks URLs. so how i extract them

Comment: You can add two arrays for them and need to find from array instead of string.

Comment: but how can i check if i don't know the next value of "my-product-name-display" and "BYADE3323", please help

Comment: is `ex` in the url fixed?

Comment: Yes it is fixed in url

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fetch from URL values.

pass url to the function. You can extract it.

Here is the URL : 
https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/

So when u want only `BYADE3323` this value.
When you print `$parts` array, you can find every values after your Host name.
Where your host name is https://www.example.com.

```
function GetStringAfterSecondSlashInURL($the_url)
    {
        $parts = explode("/",$the_url,3);

        if(isset($parts[2]))
            return $parts[2];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_url()` function this will help you definitely.

You can refer it from official PHP site: [parse-url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos to identify weather 'my-product-name-display' is exist s in url or not and execute code accordingly.

```
strpos($url_param, 'my-product-name-display') !== false
```

Modified code:

```
function get_product_title($url_param) {
  $get_asin = explode('/ex/', $url_param);
  $get_asin_final = explode('/', $get_asin[1]);
  $asin_v2 = $get_asin_final[0];
  return $asin_v2;
}

$url_param = "https://www.example.com/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/";
$url_param = "https://www.example.com/my-product-name-display/ex/BYADE3323/wgsi?nfh3420000ooo2323nfnf/";
$product_name = '';
if (strpos($url_param, 'my-product-name-display') !== false) {
  $e_product_title = explode('.com/', $url_param);
  if (isset($e_product_title)) {
    $product_title = $e_product_title[1];
    //now explode the ex
    $product_name = get_product_title($product_title);
  }
  echo "my product name display" . $product_name;
}
else {
  $product_name = get_product_title($url_param);
  echo $product_name;
}
```

Comment: here "my-product-name-display" is not fixed, that why it is creating issue. while extracting the data.

Comment: You mean, position of "my-product-name-display" is not fixed and you want to exact product name from it? Do you have some other sample urls?

Comment: Yes position of "my-product-name-display" is not fixed, and may be it not available into URL, sample url you have used in above code,